# Why need to call here @Html.DxaRegion("Header") again to get it work?

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

Article Page Template contains
[image: system/include/header system/include/footer]

It says that header region is included as Region on the Page, with works.
header.html uses "Include page (Header)" Page template & "Include page (header)" Page Schema.

That Page schema contains only 1 region, Header:

[image]

and Region Schema "[Header] Region" contains Component based on Schema "Menu".

Component is filled in region "Header" on the header.html Page.
note: Core example has here 3 calls to the nested regions.

[image]

### Question

Why need to call here @Html.DxaRegion("Header") again to get it work?
Region view header first time contains model see figure (Regions count 1, Entities count 0)
When execute `@Html.DxaRegions()` same view is called.
Second time @Html.DxaEntities works (it is levelt up).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: because your Include Page itself is "transformed" into a Region (along with its nested Regions and their CPs). There is no way around this.

Comment: I don’t think that placing CPs directly on the Include Page changes the situation; those CPs are implicitly put in a “Main” Region, so you will still have nested Region Models: the top one represents the Include Page and it contains a nested “Main” Region Model containing the Entity Models.

Comment: No change indeed. Maybe there is way to call @Html.DxaEntities() in the first call (Header.cshtml), using the first region.

Comment: Is there a real problem with this extra level? The general idea is that an Include Page can contain multiple Regions, which translate to nested Region Models.

Comment: Thanxs. If there is no shortcut it's fine. Maybe some ms cost when not in cache.

Comment: it applies to header/footer/tools(breadcrumb) for us.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I kinda jumped the gun there, edited my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Solved it with: @{
    if (Model.Regions.ContainsKey("Header"))
    {
        @Html.DxaRegion("Header")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DxaEntities()
    }
}